# modify jquery slideshow code to autoplay

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I found [some code in an article on daniweb.com](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/web-development/threads/366543/image-slideshow-from-database-phpjquery) for a jquery slideshow and got it working pulling data from mysql. I want to modify it so the slide changes automatically every 5 seconds or so, instead of having to click the buttons but don't know how to modify this code to do that...

Here's the current code: It uses a mysql database and php to pull used car info from a table and then display in a slideshow. The idea is to run this on a rasPi with a 7-10" display at our cashier counter or waiting room for customers to see...

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var currentPosition = 0;
  var slideWidth = 950;
  var slides = $('.slide');
  var numberOfSlides = slides.length;
  // Remove scrollbar in JS
  $('#slidesContainer').css('overflow', 'hidden');
  // Wrap all .slides with #slideInner div
  slides
    .wrapAll('<div id="slideInner"></div>')
    // Float left to display horizontally, readjust .slides width
 .css({
      'float' : 'left',
      'width' : slideWidth
    });
  // Set #slideInner width equal to total width of all slides
  $('#slideInner').css('width', slideWidth * numberOfSlides);
  // Insert controls in the DOM
  $('#slideshow')
    .prepend('<span class="control" id="leftControl">Clicking moves left</span>')
    .append('<span class="control" id="rightControl">Clicking moves right</span>');
  // Hide left arrow control on first load
  manageControls(currentPosition);
  // Create event listeners for .controls clicks
  $('.control')
    .bind('click', function(){
    // Determine new position
 currentPosition = ($(this).attr('id')=='rightControl') ? currentPosition+1 : currentPosition-1;
 // Hide / show controls
    manageControls(currentPosition);
    // Move slideInner using margin-left
    $('#slideInner').animate({
      'marginLeft' : slideWidth*(-currentPosition)
    });
  });
  // manageControls: Hides and Shows controls depending on currentPosition
  function manageControls(position){
    // Hide left arrow if position is first slide
 if(position==0){ $('#leftControl').hide() } else{ $('#leftControl').show() }
 // Hide right arrow if position is last slide
    if(position==numberOfSlides-1){ $('#rightControl').hide() } else{ $('#rightControl').show() }
  } 
  
  
});
```

```css
*  {
  font-family:Arial;
  
  }

body {
  width:800px;
  height:572px;
  background:linear-gradient(#117dc8,#15527c);
  
  }
  
.header  {
   color:white;
   font-size:28px;
   margin-left:20px;
   margin-top:10px;
   }
   
.logo  {
   position:absolute;
   margin-left:720px;
   margin-top:-30px;
   z-index:10;
   width:250px;
   
   }
   
.container {
   position:relative;
   background-color:#fafafa;
   width:940px;
   height:480px;
   border-radius:10px;
   margin-top:10px;
   margin-left:6px;
   padding:5px;
   z-index:6;
   
   }
   
#carDisplay {
   width:915px;
   height:455px;
   padding:10px;
   border:none;
   
   }
   
.contact {
   position:absolute;
   color:white;
   margin:15px 80px;
   font-size:20px;

   }

*  {
  font-family:Arial;
  
  }
  
#cert {
  color:#e3001b;   
  
  }
 
.cartitle {
   font-size:30px;
   margin-left:10px;
   
   } 

.stock  {
   font-size:14px;
   font-size:18px;
   color:#999;
   margin-left:10px;
   
   }
 
.carimg  {
  width:480px;
  padding:5px;
  margin-left:10px;
  box-shadow:0px 2px 5px 1px #bbb;
  
  }
  
.details {
   padding:30px;
   font-size:25px;
   
   }
   
.price {
  font-size:35px;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:#333;
  text-align:center;
  margin-top:-20px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Used Car New Arrivals</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mainstyle.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/framestyle.css">

<script src="jscript.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

 <div class="header"><i>Used Car New Arrivals | </i><span style="font-size:20px;">Falmouth Toyota</span></div>
 <img class="logo" src="ft-logo.png" />

 <div class="container">
 
 <?php

 $servername = "localhost";
 $username = "root";
 $password = "root";
 $dbname = "usedcars";

 // Create connection
 $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
 // Check connection
 if (!$conn) {
     die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
 }

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM usedcars";
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
 $num = mysql_num_rows($result);
 
 if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
     // output data of each row
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

 echo "<div id='slideshow'>
     <div id='slidesContainer'>
       <div class='slide'>

<table class='tableStyle'>
 
 <tr>
  <td colspan='2'><div class='stock'>Stock: " . $row["stock"] ."</div></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td colspan='2'><div class='cartitle'><b><span id='cert'>" . $row["certified"] . "</span> " . $row["preowned"]. " " . $row["year"] . " " . $row["make"] . " " . $row["model"] . " " . "</b><span style='font-size:18px;color:#999;'> - " . number_format($row["mileage"]) . " miles</span></div></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td colspan='2'><hr /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><img class='carimg' src='" .$row["img"] . "' /></td>
  <td class='details'><div class='price'>Price: $" . number_format($row["price"]) ."</div><br>
  <hr style='margin-top:-25px;'/>
   <b>Vehicle Features</b>
   <ul>
    <li>" . $row["feat1"] . "</li>
    <li>" . $row["feat2"] . "</li>
    <li>" . $row["feat3"] . "</li>
    <li>" . $row["feat4"] . "</li>
   </ul>
  </td>
 <tr>
</table>
       
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>";
     }
 }


 else {
     echo "<span>No images available</span>";
 }

 mysqli_close($conn);
 ?>

 </div>
 
 <div class="contact">VISIT OUR SHOWROOM FOR MORE INFORMATION ON ANY OF THESE VEHICLES</div>

</body>

<script src="jscript.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the following code inside a script tag. Feel free to change the slide change duration as per your requirement.

Here 5000 means 5*1000 milli seconds, which is 5 seconds.

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    $('#rightControl.control').click();
}, 5000);
```

Accept this answer if it helps.

Update: Playing the slideshow continuously (looping)

Note: Replace the existing animate function with the below snippet

```
$('#slideInner').animate({
    'marginLeft' : slideWidth*(-currentPosition)
}, function() {
    // if last slide then move the pointer to 1st slide
    if(currentPosition == numberOfSlides-1) {
        currentPosition = -1;
    }
});
```

Comment: This worked. What else can I to make it go back to the first slide in the table once it has reached the last?

Comment: @mrmills129 please take a look at the updated solution